# How can reload page with new content in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can i create a button that when user click on the button, the page will refresh and show new content?

Answer (score 0):

Call the `setState(() {})` method. You need a `StatefulWidget` for that.
Your code will be something like

```dart
 RaisedButton(
    child : Text("Tap"),
    onPressed : () {
        setState(() {
          // modifiy the state
        })
    }
  ),
```

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/XHpYqPTlKrIcPlJ3fr/giphy.gif  

Exactly i want this , look when click on button show a new content and if click again show previous content

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Codepen example of the code below](https://codepen.io/FirasDev/pen/zYvmxpY)

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  counter++;
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Flat Button",
              ),
            ),
            Text(
          'Counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
            Text(
          '$counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/XHpYqPTlKrIcPlJ3fr/giphy.gif 

Exactly i want this , look when click on button show a new content and if click again show previous content